# location of the Object got uploaded onto Amazon S3

Tags: image, amazon-s3, location

Say i have an image that get uploaded onto Amazon S3, I wonder if S3 can return me an URL in the response indicating where the image is located such that I can cache the url. The url then could be used to show the image on the user's browser. I didn't seem to find such info on S3 documentation, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for S3 to return the url to you. When you upload to S3, you need to specify the bucket(folder) and key(filename) so you can easily create the url to the file yourself.

eg `http://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket]/[key]`

If your content is [private](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingAuthAccess.html) you'll need to create a [signed url](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?S3_QSAuth.html) but all the SDKs and libraries make this easy.